# Converting Deferred Helper To TypeScript Class

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I convert the following js code from MDN to a TypeScript class and use it like `new Deferred()`?

```
function Deferred() {
// update 062115 for typeof
if (typeof(Promise) != 'undefined' && Promise.defer) {
    //need import of Promise.jsm for example: Cu.import('resource:/gree/modules/Promise.jsm');
    return Promise.defer();
} else if (typeof(PromiseUtils) != 'undefined'  && PromiseUtils.defer) {
    //need import of PromiseUtils.jsm for example: Cu.import('resource:/gree/modules/PromiseUtils.jsm');
    return PromiseUtils.defer();
} else {
    /* A method to resolve the associated Promise with the value passed.
     * If the promise is already settled it does nothing.
     *
     * @param {anything} value : This value is used to resolve the promise
     * If the value is a Promise then the associated promise assumes the state
     * of Promise passed as value.
     */
    this.resolve = null;

    /* A method to reject the assocaited Promise with the value passed.
     * If the promise is already settled it does nothing.
     *
     * @param {anything} reason: The reason for the rejection of the Promise.
     * Generally its an Error object. If however a Promise is passed, then the Promise
     * itself will be the reason for rejection no matter the state of the Promise.
     */
    this.reject = null;

    /* A newly created Promise object.
     * Initially in pending state.
     */
    this.promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        this.resolve = resolve;
        this.reject = reject;
    }.bind(this));
    Object.freeze(this);
}
}
```

Comment: Frame challenge: stop using `Deferred` objects in the first place! You should never need these.

Comment: Please show us your attempt at adding TypeScript annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class Deferred<T = any> {
  private _promise: Promise<T>;
  private _resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void;
  private _reject: (reason?: any) => void;
  constructor() {
    this._promise = new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
      this._resolve = resolve;
      this._reject = reject;
    });
  }

  get promise() {
    return this._promise;
  }
  resolve(value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) {
    this._resolve(value);
  }
  reject(reason?: any) {
    this._reject(reason);
  }
}
```

Comment: Introducing extra methods and getters seems overly complicated. Why not just assign the values directly to `public readonly` properties?